# Make entire page fit the viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get the entire site to fit the viewport so no scrolling is needed. The index, music, and contact are the main ones as the other 2 pages link to an outside source (link to the site is at the bottom of the post).

These are what I have tried and none of them have worked. Maybe I am implementing them incorrectly.

- Setting the body to max-height of 100vh didn't work. I wrapped the entire page in a div that and set it to max-height of 100vh and it didn't work either.
- This didn't work either

  ```
     html body {
     margin: 0;
     min-height: 100%;
  }
  ```
- Same as the option above but this time with vh instead of percentage

  ```
      html body {
     min-height: 100vh;
     position: relative; //the reason I added this one was so later on I can
                          make the footer sticky to the bottom of the page 
     margin: 0;
  }
  ```
- I also found a javascript that someone had tried from another question (which it would simply add css to the cover div (or for me the body tag or the div container that I have all the content wrapped in) to have a css equal to 100 viewport height and width.

  ```
  var vHeight = $(window).height(),
  vWidth = $(window).width(),
  cover = $('.cover');

  cover.css({"height":vHeight,"width":vWidth});
  ```

this did not work either.

Any hints or clues on how to achieve this?

link to the site: 
http://www.instastatus.live/

edit:

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <section id="intropage">
        <section id="container-banner">
            <div class="section first">
                <div class="cont_title">
                    <h1><a href="music.html">Music</a></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <div class="cont_title">
                    <h1><a href="tour.html">Tour</a></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <div class="cont_title">
                    <h1 class="font-weight-bold">Members<br>Only</h1>
                    <h3>Free Song<br>upon Sign-Up</h3>
                    <a href="http://www.holyrollerbaby.com/members/">
                        <button class="btn hoverable">Enter</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <div class="cont_title">
                    <h1><a href="https://holyrollerbabyofficialstore.bigcartel.com/">Store</a></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <div class="cont_title">
                    <h1><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>



<div class="video-container">
    <video autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="http://www.icutpeople.com/wp-content/themes/icutpeople/assets/video/waynesworld.mp4"
                type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <div class="overlay-desc text-center">
        <h1 class="white-text">"Spread Your Love Around" <br>Music Video Out Now!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-icons">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/holyrollerbaby/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/holyrollerbaby/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9xenomg5a4OcN0wz4X2msg?view_as=subscriber"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*===== Media ====*/
@media (max-width: 800px){
    #container-banner{
        height: 60vh;;
    }
    video{
        height: 40vh;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 640px){
    #container-banner{
        height: 70vh;;
    }
    video{
        height: 30vh;
        object-fit: cover;

    }
}
@media (width: 200px){
    #container-banner{
        height: 80vh;;
    }
    video{
        height: 20vh;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
}
    /*==== video description ===*/

.video-container {
    position: relative;

}
video {
    min-height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 50vh;
}
.overlay-desc {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: start;
    justify-content: center;
}
.overlay-icons {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
}


    /*home page*/
#container-banner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
#container-banner:hover > .section {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(22%);
    filter: brightness(22%);
}
#container-banner:hover > .section:hover {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
    filter: brightness(100%);
}
#container-banner .section {
    flex-grow: 1;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
}
#container-banner .section .cont_title {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15vh;
}
#container-banner .section .cont_title h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    font-size: 3.5vw;
    margin: 0;
    transition: font-size 0.3s;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#container-banner .section .cont_title h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3vw;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#container-banner .section .cont_desc {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 12vw;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.8s, padding-top 0.9s, -webkit-transform 0.7s;
    transition: opacity 0.8s, transform 0.7s, padding-top 0.9s;
    transition: opacity 0.8s, transform 0.7s, padding-top 0.9s, -webkit-transform 0.7s;
    padding-top: 6vh;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
#container-banner .section .cont_desc p {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#container-banner .section:hover {
    flex-grow: 1.8;
    transition: flex 0.2s;
}
#container-banner .section:hover > .cont_title h1 {
    font-size: 5.3vw;
    transition: font-size 0.4s;
}
#container-banner .section:hover > .cont_title h3 {
    font-size: 1.6vw;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
#container-banner .section:hover > .cont_desc {
    opacity: 1;
    padding-top: 2vh;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    transition: opacity 0.7s, padding-top 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.1s;
    transition: opacity 0.7s, padding-top 0.5s, transform 0.1s;
    transition: opacity 0.7s, padding-top 0.5s, transform 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0.1s, 0s;
}
#container-banner .section:nth-child(1) {
    background: url("../img/members/2nd-round.jpg") center;
}
#container-banner .section:nth-child(2) {
    background: url("../img/members/3rd-round.jpg") center;

}
#container-banner .section:nth-child(3) {
    background: url("../img/HRBAlbumCover.svg") center;
    object-fit: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    background-color: black;
}
#container-banner .section:nth-child(4) {
    background: url("../img/members/3.jpg") center;
}
#container-banner .section:nth-child(5) {
    background: url("../img/members/4.jpg") center;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.logo{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../HRB Album Cover.svg");
    background-position: center;

}
.cont_title h1 a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.fluidMedia {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* proportion value to aspect ratio 16:9 (9 / 16 = 0.5625 or 56.25%) */
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fluidMedia iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
label{
    color: black;
}

.nav-link, .nav-item{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: var(--blue);
    font-family: ReginaBlack-Solid;
}
.regina-black-solid{
    font-family: ReginaBlack-Solid;
}


.nav-item a:hover{
    color: var(--yellow) !important;
}



.blue-text{
    color: var(--blue);
}

.yellow-text{
    color: var(--yellow);
}
```

Comment: You've already set the `height` of `section` to `75vh`, why not set the height of the video to `25vh`? You also need to remove the default `margin` on `body`

Comment: Post the HTML markup that demonstrates the layout in the question

Comment: I added the HTML and CSS code. on different screen sizes, the video snaps up leaving a huge white space at the bottom of it. I have added a few media query to fix these but on some screens, it is still snapping up. I don't want to end up with 6 different media queries but I don't know what else to do? Do I add a rang to my media queries or is there something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You set your container-banner to 75vh. You can't fit the video in there with the banner taking up 75% of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

What would work best if if you put a wrapper container around your site and then you set that to be positioned absolutely and full width and height of the site

so for example

```
.site-container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    /*IF YOU REALLY WANT TO FORCE THE ISSUE*/
    overflow: hidden;
}

.All subsequent child{
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.